# Why does my web application timeout using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ms-word, office-interop

I have been using using `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word` in my webserver (yes, i know it is not recommended). When I ran it on my machine, it runs fine, but when running on the server I get a timeout on the following line:

```
Documents.Open //when trying to open the file.
```

Is there something I'm missing? Is there a better way to edit a Word document within web servers/websites? (I can't create a new one using string builder or outputting into file; I need to edit an existing one that sits on the server.)

Any input will be appreciated as I'm stuck on this for few days already...

Comment: Editing Word documents within web servers/websites is about the strangest thing I've heard today. Why do you possibly need to do this? Are you *building* a Word document on the server from information input by the user? Or are you trying to allow the user to create a Word document over the Internet without having to buy and install Office?

Comment: LOL, 
I'm glad this was the strangest thing you have heard.
just b.c you asked the reason im doing this is: We have an internal website  that needs to modify a word doc that sits on the server according to the user info and print it straight after (then discard the document). The alternative (which I'm using now) is to create a website that populate the information and prints itself, but b.c we wanted to use some of the words qualities I tried using word.
Anyway it didn’t work…

Answer (score 0):

Never use any of the Office applications from a server application. It's unsupported, quite possibly illegal, and in any case, doesn't work.

Comment: any ideas on how to programatically modify a word document then?

Comment: Wuser: there are many commercial products that allow you to do that. "Aspose" is one of them.

Comment: This is not a constructive answer, "doesn't work" is not informative. I have an issue with class procedures here timing out, some direction on debugging would be great.

Comment: It is a horrible idea to use Office Interop from ASP.NET or another server technology. These APIs were written for use in a desktop application, for automating Office (a suite of desktop applications). Server applications are different in many ways that make it a very, very bad idea to use Office Interop in them. It's also unsupported by Microsoft, and may violate your Office license. See [Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757)

Answer (score 0):

Just because you can use Office applications on the server doesn't mean you should.  Among the problems is that Office automation is single-threaded.

John Saunders is right that commercial products are a good way to go to create a Word document on the server.  Aspose makes a product that does it, as does their competitor, SoftArtisans, with whom I worked for a short time.  Though I know of open source products that can create Excel files, I haven't found any for Word.

One last bit: the APIs for the .xlsx and .docx file formats are public.  They aren't terribly easy to use, however.

Answer (score 0):

I think you dont have Office in server.The best way is use DocX for modify docx files.
https://docx.codeplex.com/

```
     using (DocX document = DocX.Load(filename))
        {
            document.ReplaceText(a, b);
            document.Save();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I've had automated office applications running on servers since office 97 came out, without issue, in both C++ and C#. They generate several hundred reports every single day, both queued and on demand, in multiple formats, depending on requirements, all driven by the output extension (doc/docx, xls/xlsx, pdf, html, bmp, jpg) from word templates and DataTables generated from functions in shared assemblies.

Automation hangs are usually caused by bad or missing arguments and with web servers and automation servers, writing to the event log is key to determining where issues arise. Make a good reusable library of functions to do the automation and test the crap out of them. Then using it in other projects is trivial and you won't waste time continually working out issues.

Comment: I think this should be a comment. It does not attempt to answer the OP's question.

Answer (score 0):

permissions, permissions and permissions,
google for example office interop DCOMCNFG